# AWS API gateway giving 403 error while accessing from EC2 in Private Subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, api-gateway

I have EC2 Instance running in private subnet and want to access API Gateway.

Steps i did:-

1. Created and Deployed stage in API gateway
2. Tested from test URL and postman - working fine
3. Created VPC Endpoint with execute-api interface
4. Updated API-Gateway resource policy as below and saved

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:eu-west-1:{{MY_ACCOUNT}}:{{MYAPI}}/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "aws:sourceVpc": "vpce-{{ID}}"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

5. tried accessing from EC2 using curl and wget getting 403

```
[ec2-user@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx ~]$ wget https://{{MYAPI}}.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/DEV/CustomerInfo/?customerId={{CUST_ID}}
--2020-06-29 14:43:29--  https://{{MYAPI}}.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/DEV/CustomerInfo/?customerId={{CUST_ID}}
Resolving {{MYAPI}}.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com ({{MYAPI}}.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com)... xx.xx.xx.xx, xx.xx.xx.xxx
Connecting to {{MYAPI}}.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com ({{MYAPI}}.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com)|xx.xx.xx.xx|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2020-06-29 14:43:29 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

Even tried this in VPC endpoint
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your condition:

```
"Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "aws:sourceVpc": "vpce-{{ID}}"
                }
            }
```

does not seem right. `StringNotEquals` means that you allow `execute-api:Invoke` as long as the  `aws:sourceVpc` is **different** than `"vpce-{{ID}}`.

I believe it should be `StringEquals` instead.

Comment: yes i want vpce-{{ID}} to be white listed to access api. i tried "StringEquals" but it did not help.  Anything else should i look for ?

Comment: @ANUJAGARWAL If you temporary remove the condition fully, does it work or still nothing?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to troubleshoot and resolve the issue.

Steps i did

1. Updated API Resource Policy condition to below

```
"Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:sourceVpce": "vpce-{{ID}}"
                }
            }
```

2. In my VPC endpoint Security Group updated Inbound Rule to accept HTTPS request on port 443
3. Saved and Redeployed API

Key takeaway was to redeploy API whenever you change anything in API.

It worked :)